# What is zero weight vertex and why do i have to erase them?

Tags: opengl, blender, vertex, 3d-rendering

I am trying to working on rendering 3D animation using Assimp and opengl. While I am googling,I saw someone has mentioned, "zero weight vertex." So, I was wondering what is zero weight vertices? And why do i have to get rid of them?

Comment: In what context was this statement made?

Comment: I was trying to parse 3D Animation with assimp and opengl and wondering why my parser cannot parse a specific example file. Someone gave me a link to help by mentioning, "get rid of zero vertices." This is the link. https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/vertex_groups/weight_edit.html

Comment: That link says nothing about "zero vertices".